# Handle click event or MouseDown in a disabled WPF StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, click, stackpanel, disabled-control

It's been a while I'm trying to do something like that and I am about throwing a NotImplementedException now... I mean, throwing in the towel. You are my last hope.

So, there is my goal: Enabling a StackPanel when the user has clicked on it for user-friendly purpose.

I've got some items in this disabled StackPanel which is inside a ScrollViewer inside a Grid inside a Window.

There is a part of my code for understanding:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="30" MaxHeight="30"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="22" MaxHeight="22"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="155" Height="155"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="130"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="25" MaxHeight="25"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="22" MaxHeight="22"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="355" Width="360" />
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="330" />
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="280" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel IsEnabled="False" IsEnabledChanged="ioStackPanel_IsEnabledChanged">
            <Grid Height="22">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I tried something like that already:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MouseDown="ScrollViewer_MouseDown">

private void ScrollViewer_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Well done bro!");
}
```

But nothing is raised. No MessageBox is displayed.

Comment: When you set IsEnabled to false the Control will stop responding to input. So the first do not disable the stack panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is working fine, follow it.

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="30" MaxHeight="30" />
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="22" MaxHeight="22" />
        <RowDefinition Height="155" MinHeight="155" />
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="130" />
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="25" MaxHeight="25" />
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="22" MaxHeight="22" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="360" MinWidth="355" />
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="330" />
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="280" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="InnerPanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown_1"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Name="InnerPanel"
                    Background="Gray"
                    IsEnabled="False"
                    IsEnabledChanged="StackPanel_IsEnabledChanged_1">
            <Grid>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Inner Panel" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>


private void InnerPanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

This is working fine and implement your logic in the above event.

Comment: So, like that it's annoying because the event is raised everytime the user is clicking. But with a simple condition "if(item is not enabled) then enable it" it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately when a control is disabled, it consumes all its events and does nothing.

How about using a grid to put it behind a transparent panel. When the user clicks on the panel then you hide the panel and enable your stackpanel.

Something like...

```
<scrollviewer ...>
  <grid> <!--New grid just to align the two panels-->
     <stackpanel x:Name="enableMe" IsEnabled="False" ...>
        ....
     </stackpanel>
     <border x:name="hideMe" Background="Transparent" Click="EnableStackPanel" ZIndex="1"/>
 </grid>
</stackpanel>

public void EnableStackPanel(...)
{
  enableMe.IsEnabled=true;
  hideMe.Visibilty = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: I did not want to try something like that, but I almost did before the Ramesh's answer.